# get size of ResultSet by using SELECT COUNT(*)

Tags: java, ms-access, count

I want to retrieve all the data from database, and at the same time, I want to know how many rows of data I get. And this is my SQL:

```
rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*), * FROM tblUser");
```

Is this a valid SQL statement? and after I retrieved all the data, how to set them into different variables? For example, I have a column called `UserID`in the database, I can simply get it by using `rs.getString('UserID')`, but how to get the result of the `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I would say that's not valid SQL. The count() would have to be done separately generally. Count will return only 1 record.

Comment: Do a normal select and get the row count form the result set

Comment: You're doing it wrong if you think you need to know.  Create a List of objects, bind the object(s) associated with a row, and add to the List.  Close the result set and return the List.  The size of the List tells you how many rows came back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your SQL is *not* valid.  The ANSI standard way to do what you want uses window functions:

```
select count(*) over () as total_cnt,
       u.*
from tblUser u;
```

This adds a new column to every row -- which seems to be what you want.  There are other mechanisms, depending on the underlying database for doing this.

Comment: what is that 'u' for? what does it called? and how to get the data from 'rs'?

Comment: u is an alias for tblUser. It allows shorter SQL statements. u.* is the same as tblUser.*. 

You get the data via `rs.getInt(1)` or `rs.getInt("total_cnt")`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative if your RDBMS doesn't support window functions

```
rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT B.cnt, U.* 
                     FROM tblUser U, 
                     (SELECT count(*) cnt FROM tblUser) B");
```

Answer (score 0):

The results you request are not interrelated, so run two queries:

```
rs1 = s.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUser");
rs2 = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblUser");
```

and retrieve the values (one only for rs1) the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to count the rows in resultset

```
String query = "Select * from tblUser";
rs = s.executeQuery(query);

 public int getCount(ResultSet rs) {
  int rows = 0;
  while(rs.next()) {
     i++;
  }
  return i;
}
```

This way you can get the resultset as well as count

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already accessing the recordset within VBA probably the simplest was to return the count of the record set is to:

```
rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblUser");
If Not rs.EOF Then
    ' Important: You must move to the last record to 
    ' obtain the count of the full recordset
    rs.MoveLast
    rsCount = rs.RecordCount
    ' Remember to Return to the First Record so that you can 
    ' continue to use the recordset
    rs.MoveFirst
End If
```